# Custom domain for Google Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I cannot figure out why I'm experiencing issues with buckets setup to serve content under custom domain. I have few that work just fine, few others that have been working before and do not now, and few I'm struggling to setup from scratch and cannot make them to work.

Here's what I do:

1. I setup an app on Google App Engine.
2. I setup a bucket named gcs.domain.com which prompts me to verify domain first with Google
   Webmasters Tools and domain TXT record - after that I'm able to
   create a bucket.
3. I setup CNAME to be able to access bucket under my
   custom domain.
4. I add Service Account Name as an owner of the bucket, so my app can write and read from it.

When I run my app I get PHP Fatal error Invalid Google Cloud Storage path: gs://gcs.domain.com CloudStorageStreamWrapper.php on line 327

I cannot pin point why. This scenario works on some of the domains and apps and does not on others. I can setup a bucket with a regular name that works just fine. The problem seems to be only with custom domain buckets.

Comment: gs://gcs.domain.com is a bucket name. Are you trying to read or write an object? You'll need to specify that as well: gs://gcs.domain.com/someObject.txt

Comment: both, that's exactly how I'm trying access it with PHP runtime.